# The number of roots of $f'$

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

$f$ is a polynomial. And has root on $a$ and $b$. There is no roots between $(a,b)$. How do I prove that $f'$ has odd number roots between $(a,b)$?

I can imagine the graph so I can guess there are odd numbers. But how could I prove it ?

Answer (score 1):

This claim need not be true.

You can verify yourself : $f(x)=6x^4-8x^3-12x^2+24x-96$ Between the two roots of the function, its derivative has two roots.

Comment: One root of $f'$ is a double root.  I guess the OP meant "counted with multiplicity".

Comment: Yeah I m really sorry about it. There is one more condition that multiplicity is counted 2

Comment: @lhf in that case, it is true. Because it’s monotonicity must have changed odd numbered times.